# External monitor and colour adjustment on ThinkPad T440p

Tags: multiple-monitors, brightness

I'm new to Linux, and have sorted out inital issues with two exceptions. One is that my ThinkPad doesn't detect my Benq external monitor, either via VGA or miniDSP-to-HDMI. System settings > Displays > Detect Displays does nothing. The other is that neither f.lux nor Redshift are able to affect the laptop screen's brightness. I'd like one of them to work on my laptop as well as on the external monitor.

Laptop is a ThinkPad T440p running Ubuntu 14.04. The command lspci gives:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06). No drivers are suggested in "Additional drivers".

I've read extensively online about both issues with no success. I would like to solve them without reinstalling the operating system.